# cannot read property 'map' of undefined - react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

RestaurantItems.js

```
export default function RestaurantItems(props) {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} style={{ marginBottom: 30 }}>
            {props.restaurantsData.map((restaurant, index) => (
                <View key={index}
                    style={{ marginTop: 10, padding: 15, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                    <RestaurantImage image={restaurtant.image_url} />
                    <RestaurantInfo name={restaurtant.name} rating={restaurtant.rating} />
                </View>
            ))}
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
}
```

I've been stuck with this problem for hours, and I cannot figure it out.
Should I define map in anywhereelse?

```
    useEffect(() => {
        getRestaurantsFromYelp();
    }, []);

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ backgroundColor: "#eee", flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={{ backgroundColor: "white", padding: 15 }}>
                <HeaderTabs />
                <SearchBar />
            </View>
            <ScrollView showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
                <Categories />
                <RestaurantItems restaurantsData={restaurantsData} />
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
```

I put them in the Home.js.

Comment: props.restaurantsData is what's not defined. Make sure you're passing your props correctly. You can also use `?.` (optional chaining)

Comment: @Abe I put them in the Home.js

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.